# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Default constructor for class com.b.de is not accessible

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, google-play

I'm using Parse SDK and in my last release update for the Play Store. 
I got the error above with my beta testers:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Default constructor for class com.b.de is not accessible.
    at com.parse.ParseObjectSubclassingController.registerSubclass(ParseObjectSubclassingController.java)
    at com.parse.ParseObject.getObjectController(ParseObject.java)
```

In debug mode it is all Ok. It's the first time with this problem in my app (version code 17)

Do you know how can I solve this? Or any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say it's OK in debug, presumably running from your IDE, but I would guess that  is not also the case for your beta testers.  Are you using a build tool?  All dependencies accounted for in the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the proguard-rules.pro to keep the Parse public class.

```
-keep public class com.parse.**
```

If you have a problem like that, you can `dontobfuscate` to know what class is being removed.

Comment: Can you please offer more details? I am having the same issue like you. Thanks!